# How to combine two queries that have ORDER BY using UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union-all

I have two query that each of them has its own `order by` like this:

Query1:

```
SELECT id, name, title, content 
FROM table where match(title, content) against('anything') 
Order By title
```

Query1:

```
SELECT id, tag, question, answer 
FROM table 
Where tag like '%anything' 
Order By tag, question
```

Now how can I combine them using `UNION ALL`?

Comment: How do you want the result to be ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the results by:

1. result type (MATCH or LIKE)
2. title (for MATCH) or tag (for LIKE)
3. NULL (for MATCH) or question (for LIKE)

You can either use nested queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS result_type, id, name, title, content 
    FROM table
    WHERE MATCH (title, content) AGAINST ('anything') 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, id, tag, question, answer 
    FROM table 
    WHERE tag LIKE '%anything' 
) AS foobar
ORDER BY
    result_type,
    CASE result_type WHEN 1 THEN title ELSE tag END,
    CASE result_type WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE question END
```

Or you can add sort helper columns:

```sql
(
SELECT 1 AS sort_1, title AS sort_2, NULL     AS sort_3, id, name, title, content 
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (title, content) AGAINST ('anything') 
) UNION ALL (
SELECT 2 AS sort_1, tag   AS sort_2, question AS sort_3, id, tag, question, answer 
FROM table 
WHERE tag LIKE '%anything' 
)
ORDER BY sort_1, sort_2, sort_3
```

Comment: Although I feel this query is not optimized. but however this is the only solution.

Comment: You can add faux columns (to help with sorting) and avoid nested query. However there is no guarantee if it makes the query faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same ordering, then the following generally works:

```
(SELECT id, name, title, content
 FROM table
 where match(title, content) against('anything')
 order by title
) union all
(SELECT id, tag, question, answer
 FROM table
 where tag like '%anything'
 order by tag, question
);
```

This works in practice, because in practice the first subquery is executed before the second.  However, I don't think the MySQL documentation guarantees the order of processing of the two.  For that guarantee, you would need an outer `order by`:

```
(SELECT id, name, title, content, 1 as priority
 FROM table
 where match(title, content) against('anything')
) union all
(SELECT id, tag, question, answer, 2 as prioirty
 FROM table
 where tag like '%anything'
)
ORDER BY priority, title, content
```

Comment: Your second query is Incomplete. because there is not `ORDER BY tag, question`. anyway +1

Comment: @Sajad . . . Of course not.  In the output set produced by the `union all`, the columns are called `title` and `content`.  Those are the names recognized by the `order by` for the `union all`.

Comment: I understand what is your mean, but look at the order: `id, name, title, content` and  `id, tag, question, answer`. Then `title, content` are the same with `question, answer`. But actually I need to `tag` instead of `answer`. And unfortunately implementing that is impossible using outer `order by` *(I think)*